# Стилистические средства в романе "Мастер и Маргарита"

Tags: стилистика

**– Котам нельзя! С котами нельзя! Брысь!Брысь! Слезай, а то милицию позову!**

Можно ли этот отрывок наряду с лексическим повтором отнести к градации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы не сказала, что это градация - явного нарастания значений  нанизываемых синонимов я не вижу, они примерно одной степени раздражённости. Экспрессивный повтор - да! Восклицание - да! Можно увидеть персонификацию - очеловечивание кота, придание ему черт хулигана.А вот на градацию "нельзя-нельзя-брысь-слезай" как-то  не похоже.